# URL Rewrite: Is my syntax of the rule wrong

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

Hello i am using a Smartasp which i allowed me to do url rewrite. I placed a rules on web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="AmazonS3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://www.blah/amazon/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://amazon.blah/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="AmazonS3 with port" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://www.blah.com:80/amazon/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://amazon.blah.com/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
```

Where i try to read the requested url : www.blah.com/amazon/ to amazon.blah.com. After typing the www.blah.com/amazon/ the browser didn't redirect to amazon page...

On my local machine where i typed the rules has a rewrite tag highlighted saying invalid rewrite under system.webserver. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way with a `http`:

```
<rule name="Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="www.blah.com/amazon/"/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://amazon.blah.com" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I have added the rules as you mention but still not going

Comment: Change the url-match to exactly like this `<match url="/amazon"/>` and check the result.

Comment: No it doesn't i use my localhost to try first. It can if i select Do not match the pattern option but this option is not i wanted.

Comment: Sorry don't know why it works now... i bascially clear the history to test it... Cool, i can fake the browser that the image is hosted by my site but in fact it was on amazon s3.

Comment: Damn it work url rewrite but couldn't fake the browser about the cross origin on canvas